# error in dyn.load in Rcpp package in mac

Tags: r, macos, installation, clang, rcpp

I have a problem in loading compiled object Rcpp compiled object.  I am compiling RcppSMC package from source. I

```
Error in dyn.load("mylib.so") : 
  unable to load shared object '/Users/avi/softwares/RcppSMC/src/mylib.so': 
  dlopen(/Users/avi/softwares/RcppSMC/src/mylib.so, 6): Symbol not found: __ZNSoD0Ev
  Referenced from: /Users/avi/softwares/RcppSMC/src/mylib.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/avi/softwares/RcppSMC/src/mylib.so
```

I am using clang for compiling with following verson. I think there is some compiling problem because if I download the mac os binary from CRAN dyn.load works.

```
Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0 

clang++ -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include -I/usr/local/include -I"/Users/avi/Library/R/3.0/library/Rcpp/include"   -fPIC  -g -O3 -pipe -std=c++0x -Wall -pedantic -c blockpfgaussianopt.cpp -o blockpfgaussianopt.o
  .....
clang++ -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib -o mylib.so blockpfgaussianopt.o history.o pflineart.o pfnonlinbs.o smc-exception.o /Users/avi/Library/R/3.0/library/Rcpp/lib/libRcpp.a -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
```

installing to /Users/avi/Library/R/3.0/library/RcppSMC/libs

This is weird problem because sourceCpp is working in the machine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're trying to install a package that links to `Rcpp` from source, you probably also need to install `Rcpp` from source.

Assuming that you're using OS X Mavericks, there have been similar posts around StackOverflow with similar problems.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. That was stupid of me. I did read about compiling Rcpp should be installed from source. But ignored it thinking that its recommended and not necessary. It definitely work smoothly when installed from source.

Comment: No problem. It only recently became necessary for Mac OSX Mavericks users, due to ABI compatibility between the older (and CRAN-used) compilers and the newer `clang` compilers. Hopefully, issues will be resolved by R 3.1.0.

Answer (score 1):

A colleague of mine got the same issue.

We tried every possible solution we found on the Internet.

We end up concluding that it was the new version of Mac (Mojave) that caused these types of issues.

He downgraded to Sierra and reinstalled everything.
That solved his problem.

Comment: I had the same issue and your solution was what I ended up doing to get it to work. Thanks for posting as I initially thought that there was a workaround with a particular MacOS version that I hadn’t discovered.

Comment: There may be some workaround but we didn't find it :/